# How do I write different small program of C in Eclipse all of which is having own main()?

Tags: c, eclipse

I've created one C project in Eclipse, after that trying to add source file and write small program. It runs smoothly for the first time. But when I'm adding another source file and writing the code inside main(), and build it , it is throwing some error.

Comment: It would really help if you'd say what this *some error* message says ... and what the code of your two source files looks like.

Comment: I suspect you have multiple files with `main` method. Only one `main` can be present, you are best off creating an `index` file of sorts with a single `main` method where you use a `switch` or some other mechanism to call methods in the other files depending on which small program you wanna run (based on probably command line arguments).

Comment: My Project name is C.
Inside it I've two source file:

1. hi.c and 
2. Hello World.c

It was fine until or unless there was HelloWorld file.

after writing two lines of code of hello world which only prints the "Hello World statement", I build the project.

Then it was throwing the error, automatically made a red cross beside main() of hi.c. And the statement is ::

"""Multiple markers at this line
 - multiple definition of `main'
 - Line breakpoint: hi.c [line: 2] """

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have two programs:

Program 1

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("I am program 1.\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Program 2

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("I am program 2.\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now you want to merge them into one program.

Rename them and add a new `main()`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int p1(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("I am program 1.\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int p2(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("I am program 2.\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("I am providing program 1 and program 2.\n");

  printf("Enter 1 for 'program 1' or 2 for 'program 2' (any other key exits).\n");

  {
    int result = EXIT_FAILURE;

    int c = getchar();
    switch (c)
    {
      case '1': 
        result = p1(argc, argv); 
        break;        

      case '2': 
        result = p2(argc, argv); 
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

---

To have this split over various files in a modular manner, you could do like this:

p1.h

```
#ifndef P1_H
#define P1_H

int p1(int argc, char ** argv);


#endif
```

p1.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "p1.h"


int p1(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("I am program 1.\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

p2.h

```
#ifndef P2_H
#define P2_H

int p2(int argc, char ** argv);


#endif
```

p2.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "p2.h"


int p2(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("I am program 1.\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "p1.h"
#include "p2.h"


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("I am providing program 1 and program 2.\n");

  printf("Enter 1 for 'program 1' or 2 for 'program 2' (any other key exits).\n");

  {
    int result = EXIT_FAILURE;

    int c = getchar();
    switch (c)
    {
      case '1': 
        result = p1(argc, argv); 
        break;        

      case '2': 
        result = p2(argc, argv); 
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alk from all the discussion it's now bit clear to me.. I've tried my own using the above concept.

Can you please describe the functionality of the header files?

Comment: @user6737558: As C does not support name mangling (name decoration) using headers (.h) the way as shown, that is including them in each relevant translation unit (.c) they allow the compiler to detect if the functions' implementation and the way they are called match. On an abstract level (by convention, not on language level) the headers could be taken as a translation units interface declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can't build your code because you're trying to put two `main()`s (i.e two starting points) in one program. If a program has multiple starting points, how will the computer know where to start?

You should create another project in order to write another program.

Comment: Isn't it possible to write different program(e.g : palindrome, matrix addition etc) in one project.

I mean to say that in Java we can create one package and inside that package we can have different different java classes which all are having different main ().

Comment: @user6737558 Probably. But even if it's possible, you shouldn't do it because you can have a hard time finding out which project contains what if each project contains multiple programs.

Comment: Java projects are a little bit different. When you try to build a Java project with multiple `public static void main`s, Eclipse asks you which main to pick as starting point and then does some black magic preventing other mains from becoming starting points.